# Ruby on Rails directory issue - No asset folder in apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, asset-pipeline

I have begun work on a Ruby on Rails project however my predecessor has already left the organisation so I am confused about the setup. I have tried to change styles via the file `project_name/app/stylesheets/default.sass` however when I commit these changes there is no difference in styling.

I am learning about Ruby on Rails and have noticed many mentions of the path being `project_name/app/assets/stylesheets/...etc...`, am I mistaken in thinking the absence of an asset folder would cause issues or is it a case of this application not using an asset pipeline (how can I check this).

How are styling changes made if not in app/stylesheets? Below is my basic directory structure:

```
-project_name
   - .sass-cache
   - .vagrant
   - app
       - controllers
       - helpers
       - models
       - stylesheets
       - views
   - bin
   - config
   - lib
   - public
   - Stored Procedures
   - task
   - test
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? Check inside Gemfile.

Comment: Theres no mention of rails in the gemfile. The ruby version is 1.9.3 engine version 1.7.18 if thats what you were looking. Let me know if theres any other information which could be useful.

Comment: Apologies for the poor formatting. I will try to adhere to the standards henceforth.

Comment: What does `rails --version` output?

Comment: If you aren't seeing any changes perhaps all your assets were precompiled? Try running `rake assets:clean`

Comment: Tried rails -v and got ruby-railties-3.2 and ruby-railties-4.0 if that makes any sense. Apologies if i come across as lacking understanding as at the moment thats exactly where i am knowledge wise.

Comment: Where would i run rake asset:clean

Comment: In your rails console, same place you did `rails -v` also after you clean your precompiled assets it may be a good idea to recompile them so you may also run `rake assets:precompile`. But if you aren't seeing the changes after you commit then it may be server-side, so you might have to do in there.

Comment: Is there anything useful in public folder? Assets are only invoked when they are requested by the browser, so that would be the first point to look at - find how stylesheets are included within your views - usually it will be somewhere in `app/views/layout/application`. Note: Since you are using sass, those files got to be compiled before they can be served to the browser - normally this is done by assets pipeline, but there is something fishy going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you may be running a version of Rails < 3.1 (prior to the introduction of the Asset Pipeline). In these older versions of Rails, the stylesheets were stored under `public/stylesheets` as plain old `.css` files.

Now these stylesheets are loaded within a *layout*. Check `app/views/layouts` to see all the layouts defined in your app as there may be more than one (by default Rails only defines a single `application.html.erb` layout). When you open the layout you should see something like this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', :media => 'all' %>
```

The above is loading `pubic/application.css` into the layout. Use this information to figure out which stylesheets are being loaded into the layout and modify accordingly.

Comment: Strangely when i update the sass file changes are propigated through to the stylesheets in public/stylesheet folder but changes arent taken into account in the site. When looking at the source code for the site the stylesheet being edited isnt showing as being linked.

Comment: So there are SASS files? Is there a `Gemfile` in the root of the app? If so, can you please paste its contents in your original question?